# can't see bit(1) fields in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have a Java application and have mapped a boolean field to a bit(1) field in MySql.

I know for sure that some rows have the value set to true and some to false, however, I can't see it from the mysql console - which is annoying when you try to debug things and understand what is going on.

Is it possible to configure mysql to display the bit(1) fields in a friendly manner?

```
mysql> select ignored from table;
+---------+
| ignored |
+---------+
|         | 
|         | 
|         | 
|         | 
|         | 
|         | 
|         | 
|         | 
|         | 
|         | 
+---------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You might consider using UNSIGNED TINYINT(1) aka BOOLEAN, as that won't give you this problem. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select ignored+0 from table;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select cast(ignored as unsigned) from table;
```